# Slow cook beef brisket slices method

Tags: slow-cooking, brisket

What's the best method for cooking beef brisket slices? I see tons of recipes for the full brisket, but I only have a couple of slices that are about an inch thick, and 9 inches long,total weight 800 grams with no bone.

I am planning to do them in the slow cooker for 8 hours on low, salt and pepper, paprika, half an onion sliced, and some chicken stock to half cover the meat, sort of like a braise.

Would love some advice from anyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process for cooking slices of brisket is the same for a whole piece, the time involved is needed to break down the tough collagen. Slices the size of yours will take a bit less time to cook than a whole piece as they will heat up faster, but it's not that much of a difference. Your proposed method should do fine.

Comment: Agreed. You can't really 'over-cook' a brisket ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! And good to know I can't overcook it :)